# Bind select options in KnockoutJS

Tags: arrays, knockout.js

I initialized an array with 3 values and later I try to add one more item to the array.
It fails and I got an exception says
"Uncaught ReferenceError: viewModel is not defined ".
Any idea why is this?

```
var ViewModel = {
        // These are the initial options
        availableCountries: ko.observableArray(['France', 'Germany', 'Spain'])
    };
    viewModel.availableCountries.push('China');

    ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive, so you need to capitalize your variables consistently everywhere they're used. To fix the error, you can make the "v" uppercase in the second statement:

```
ViewModel.availableCountries.push('China');
```

Or you can make the "V" lowercase in the first and third statements.